# Howto subclass a builtin class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class

Suppose that everytime I call the builtin method os.rename(...). I want to print its args. How would I do this?
This does not work:

```
import os
class A(os):
def rename(**args):
    print(args)
    os.rename(args)
```

Comment: `os` is not a class.

Comment: @user2357112 Adding more to your response, `os` is not a class-- it is a module. You cannot subclass a module. You can find the args at the python docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.rename#os.rename .

Comment: @user2357112  Thanks. If rename is just an ordinary function. This should work with a wrapper function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os` is not a class but you can patch `os.rename` if you like. You should first store the built-in function in a variable (so that you can restore the patch), than write a function which prints the args and then call the real function, and then assign that new function to `os.rename`:

```
import os

real_rename = os.rename
def patched_rename(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    return real_rename(*args, **kwargs)
os.rename = patched_rename
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you think you can automate this by writing a gerneric function patch(functionname), which  returns the patched function?

Comment: something like this:     def f(k):
        real_rename = k
        def patched_rename(*args, **kwargs):
            print(args, kwargs)
            return real_rename(*args, **kwargs)
        return patched_rename
    os.rename = patched_rename

Comment: Exactly I will have a look at functools. Thanks again!